# Map network location only when connected to a certain network

Tags: windows-8, network-drive

I am using Windows 8 (x64) and when I am at work I have access to a folder on the network that is at `\\foo\bar`.

I have mapped this to a drive (J:) but whenever the PC connects to another network it attempts to reconnect this mapped drive.

Is there any way I can set the drive to only connect if connected to a specific network?

Should I be connecting to it in some way other than drive mapping?

Comment: As random as this sounds, what's the make and Model? Some vendors have software for their docks that can kinda sorta do some stuff like this.

Comment: The only way I can think of is to use a "Net Use" Script that's conditioned to run only at work.
Now, the question is how can you identify this network?

Comment: @MDTGuy : Lenovo Z580

Comment: @EliadTech : Okey Doke, if there isnt a standard way of doing this I can live with the pop-up just thought I was doing somehting stupid and there might have been a better way. Thanks though!

Comment: there is (sorta) check out Lenovo's docking software, that's a start, there's gotta be a way you can kick off something from there. You have a dock right?

Comment: wait, wait, wait, just use a logon script, but have it set to only map when you're connected. make the logoff script unmap it, done and done.